# Generic Makefile with subdirectories

Tags: c, makefile

**SOLVED**

I had no *.h file for the target which made it fail to use my rule.

---

I'm trying to write a Makefile for a C project with the following project structure, but I can't really understand why my current Makefile isn't working.

```
project
|-src
|  |-tests
```

So I want to compile my tests and run them in src/tests. My current Makefile looks like this.

```
0  CC=gcc
1  FLAGS=-std=gnu11 -Wall -Werror -lcunit
2 
3  DIR_SRC=src
4  DIR_DIST=dist
5  DIR_TEST=src/tests
6 
7  SRC = $(wildcard $(DIR_SRC)/*.c)
8  TAR = $(SRC:.c=.o)
9  SRC_TEST = $(wildcard $(DIR_TEST)/*.c)
10 TAR_TEST = $(SRC_TEST:.c=.o)
11 
12 all: $(TAR)
13 
14 tests_all: $(TAR_TEST)
15 
16 tests_clean:
17     rm -f $(TAR_TEST)
18 
19 $(DIR_TEST)/%.o: $(DIR_TEST)/%.c $(DIR_TEST)/%.h
20     $(CC) -c $(FLAGS) $< -o $@
```

But when I run `make tests_all` I get this:

```
gcc    -c -o src/tests/test_tree.o src/tests/test_tree.c
```

which I'm guessing is a default rule, because if I remove my rule that's on row 19-20, the same thing is outputted.

I can't make sense of this, does anyone have a clue why it's not working?

Comment: Does the file `src/tests/test_tree.h` exist?  If not, that's why.

Comment: That was of course the problem, now I feel stupid! Thanks!

Comment: Consider changing the name of `FLAGS` to `CFLAGS`.  Then they will be used by the default rule, which is all you need for the case where there is no dependency on any header file.